# SQL Group By with Sum for each date and using max date

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, max

I've seen a lot of similar questions but nothing that quite nails my particular problem.

I have a table storing multiple positions for each account. Changes are stored as deltas. So take for example on day 1 the following...

```
AC_ID | POS_ID | ASAT       | VAL
    1 |      1 | 2016-01-01 | 100
    1 |      2 | 2016-01-01 | 200
```

The total value for `AC_ID` 1 is 300 on 01/01/2016.The next day it may update to be...

```
AC_ID | POS_ID | ASAT       | VAL
    1 |      1 | 2016-01-01 | 100
    1 |      2 | 2016-01-01 | 200
    1 |      2 | 2016-01-02 | 250
```

Now the total value for `AC_ID` 1 is 350. This is because the new record for `POS_ID` 2 overrides the previous, but the value for `POS_ID` 1 has not changed. In order to remove `POS_ID` 1 the table would change to something like...

```
AC_ID | POS_ID | ASAT       | VAL
    1 |      1 | 2016-01-01 | 100
    1 |      2 | 2016-01-01 | 200
    1 |      2 | 2016-01-02 | 250
    1 |      1 | 2016-01-03 | 0
```

Now the value changes to 250 on day 3.

I can calculate the value at any given date with a subquery like so

```
SELECT SUM(VAL) FROM POSITION P1
WHERE P1.ASAT = 
  (SELECT MAX(P2.ASAT) FROM POSITION P2
   WHERE P1.AC_ID  = P2.AC_ID
   AND   P1.POS_ID = P2.POS_ID
   AND   P2.DATE <= [CHOSEN DATE])
```

What I'd like to do now is write a single query that will give me the total value for every `AC_ID` for every `ASAT`. If not for the delta storage mechanism I could easily achieve this using

```
SELECT AC_ID, ASAT, SUM(VAL) FROM POSITION
GROUP BY AC_ID, ASAT
ORDER BY ASAT DESC
```

What I'm looking for is something that will achieve the above but take into account the join back on the table. If I use the above then I'll only get totals for anything that changed on the `ASAT` date and not all of the existing values that haven't changed.

In the above example that should equate to a resultset of

```
AC_ID | ASAT       | SUM(VAL)
    1 | 2016-01-01 |      300
    1 | 2016-01-02 |      350
    1 | 2016-01-03 |      250
```

Here's another example of data vs output

```
AC_ID | POS_ID | ASAT       | VAL
    1 |      1 | 2016-01-01 | 100
    1 |      2 | 2016-01-01 | 200
    1 |      2 | 2016-01-02 | 250
    1 |      1 | 2016-01-03 | 0
    2 |      1 | 2016-01-02 | 500
    3 |      7 | 2016-01-02 | 1000
    3 |      7 | 2016-01-03 | 1000
    3 |     12 | 2016-01-03 | 5000
    2 |      1 | 2016-01-04 | 750
```

Result

```
AC_ID | ASAT       | SUM(VAL)
    1 | 2016-01-01 |      300
    1 | 2016-01-02 |      350
    1 | 2016-01-03 |      250
    2 | 2016-01-02 |      500
    2 | 2016-01-04 |      750
    3 | 2016-01-02 |     1000
    3 | 2016-01-03 |     6000
```

**I CHANGED HOW THIS WORKS**

Although the answers below worked the performance of them was shockingly bad (through no fault of the authors!) In order to get this to something acceptable (I need sub-second return) I refactored the table to include an `end_date` column. This column gets updated on each insert to set the life span of that row. If a row doesn't have a superseding entry then the end date is set to 9999-12-31. My example above becomes...

```
AC_ID | POS_ID | ASAT       | END_DATE   | VAL
    1 |      1 | 2016-01-01 | 2016-01-03 |  100
    1 |      2 | 2016-01-01 | 2016-01-02 |  200
    1 |      2 | 2016-01-02 | 9999-12-31 |  250
    1 |      1 | 2016-01-03 | 9999-12-31 |    0
    2 |      1 | 2016-01-02 | 2016-01-04 |  500
    3 |      7 | 2016-01-02 | 2016-01-03 | 1000
    3 |      7 | 2016-01-03 | 9999-12-31 | 1000
    3 |     12 | 2016-01-03 | 9999-12-31 | 5000
    2 |      1 | 2016-01-04 | 9999-12-31 |  750
```

I can then remove the second join from accepted answer and add an extra clause to the inner join.

```
SELECT
  p1.AC_ID, 
  p1.ASAT, 
  SUM(p2.VAL) as totalValue
FROM 
  (SELECT DISTINCT AC_ID, ASAT FROM position) p1
INNER JOIN position p2 ON
  p2.AC_ID    =  p1.AC_ID AND
  p2.ASAT     <= p1.ASAT AND
  p2.END_DATE >  p1.END_DATE
GROUP BY 
  p1.AC_ID,
  p1.ASAT;
```

Comment: What if there is no value on a given date?  Do you still want that date included?

Comment: Preferably not, i.e, I'm only interested in dates listed in the table, but if in order to achieve this I had to fill every date in between then it shouldn't be too big a deal. Date gaps are only likely to be 1 or 2 days.

Comment: To clarify, there will always be a value for any date because it will be the aggregate of the latest distinct positions prior to it. Exception to that is if date is before any positions exist in which case the result would be null/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you what you need:

```
SELECT
    P1.ac_id,
    P1.asat,
    SUM(P2.val) AS total_value
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT P.ac_id, P.asat FROM dbo.Position P) P1
INNER JOIN dbo.Position P2 ON
    P2.ac_id = P1.ac_id AND
    P2.asat <= P1.asat
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Position P3 ON
    P3.ac_id = P1.ac_id AND
    P3.pos_id = P2.pos_id AND
    P3.asat > P2.asat AND
    P3.asat <= P1.asat
WHERE
    P3.ac_id IS NULL
GROUP BY
    P1.ac_id,
    P1.asat
```

The query gets you all of your `ac_id`/`asat` combinations, then grabs any rows that might fall into those that need to be totaled, and finally uses the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and check for `NULL` to eliminate any rows that aren't the latest for that particular `pos_id`.

Comment: It certainly does work. Thanks for that, but before I accept this I'm wondering if there is something that can be optimised here. When I run my SELECT AC_ID, ASAT, SUM(VAL) FROM POSITION GROUP BY AC_ID, ASAT ORDER BY ASAT DESC it take 0.117s to execute on a table of 300k rows. The new SQL gives me the correct answer but takes in excess of 5min to complete against the same set of data. I do have an index on ac_id, pos_id, asat. Wonder if it's the 2 full table scans required.

Comment: There might be some other indexes that would optimize better, but the nature of your business rules are going to require multiple table scans. If this were another RDBMS you could likely get better performance from windowed functions, but they aren't available in MySQL. You could also try some tricks with using a variable (which is how a lot of people mimic windowed functions in MySQL), but I don't have a server available to test with right now and nothing is springing to mind for that.

Comment: Both answers were correct. This one was the most performant; albeit shockingly bad. I decided to refactor in order to decrease the query time. Have documented it as an edit on the original post.

Answer (score 1):

This is not particularly efficient, but I think it should do what you want:

```
SELECT aa.AC_ID, aa.ASAT,  SUM(p.VAL)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT AC_ID, ASAT FROM POSITION
     ) aa JOIN
     POSITION P
     ON p.AC_ID = aa.AC_ID and p.ASAT <= aa.ASAT
WHERE P.ASAT = (SELECT MAX(P2.ASAT)
                FROM POSITION P2
                WHERE P.AC_ID  = P2.AC_ID AND
                      P.POS_ID = P2.POS_ID AND
                      P2.ASAT <= aa.ASAT
               )
GROUP BY aa.AC_ID, aa.ASAT;
```

Comment: Thanks for a starting point. Unfortunately this won't work if there's more than one AC_ID. It just aggregates everything together in one line (and takes a long time doing it!)

Comment: @NathPapadacis . . . Oops, there should have been a `group by`.  This won't fix the performance issue, but the answer should be correct.

Comment: Aha, almost. It just needs one last tweak to make it work which is to change the join to check for <= on the `ASAT`. `and p.ASAT <= aa.ASAT`